how to derive ISO month from date in snowflake
it seems following function sql is not working to derive in snowflake .
TO_VARCHAR(DATE_TRUNC(''MONTH'', TO_DATE(YEAROFWEEKISO(DATE) || ''-01-01'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') + (ISO_WEEK_NUMBER - 1) * 7), ''YYYY-MM'') AS ISO_MONTH 

How to derive ISO_MONTH in snowflake

Hi - what is your definition of an ISO_MONTH, as I'm not aware of such an ISO definition (though happy to be shown that there is)?

So if I deconstruct your SQL a touch:
select
    _date,
    YEAROFWEEKISO(_DATE) as iso_year,
    WEEKISO(_date) as iso_week,
    TO_DATE(YEAROFWEEKISO(_DATE) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as aa,
    DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAROFWEEKISO(_DATE),1,1) as alternative_aa,
    
    DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', aa + (WEEKISO(_date) - 1) * 7) as bb,
    
    TO_VARCHAR(bb, 'YYYY-MM') AS ISO_MONTH
from values
    ('2024-04-30'::date)
    as t(_date);

this works, I had to swap from ISO_WEEK_NUMBER to a function the acts on a date, aka WEEKISO.

so you can change some more things:
select
    _date,
    YEAROFWEEKISO(_DATE) as iso_year,
    WEEKISO(_date) as iso_week,
    DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAROFWEEKISO(_DATE),1,1) as aa,
    aa + (WEEKISO(_date) - 1) * 7 as bb,
    DATEADD('WEEK', WEEKISO(_date) - 1, aa) as alt_bb,
    
    DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', bb) as cc,
    TRUNC(bb, 'MONTH') as alt_cc,
    
    TO_CHAR(cc, 'YYYY-MM') AS ISO_MONTH
from values
    ('2024-04-30'::date)
    as t(_date);

but the date does need truncating prior to printing, and the expression can be thus written smaller and clearer:
select
    _date,
    TO_CHAR(DATEADD('WEEK', WEEKISO(_date) - 1, DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAROFWEEKISO(_DATE),1,1)), 'YYYY-MM') as ISO_MONTH_small,
    TO_VARCHAR(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_DATE(YEAROFWEEKISO(_date) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (WEEKISO(_date) - 1) * 7), 'YYYY-MM') AS ISO_MONTH 
from values
    ('2024-04-30'::date)
    as t(_date);




_DATE
ISO_MONTH_SMALL
ISO_MONTH




2024-04-30
2024-04
2024-04



